# LVM: How to clone thin-volume

Tags: lvm

I'd like to know how it's possible using the lvm cli tool to clone an existing lvm thin volume, creating another thin-volume with the same contents (but possibly a larger size) as the original one.

So something like LXC [does](https://gist.github.com/sidnei/7041338) when you execute `lxc-clone`.

The only information I could find about creating a thin volume with another as its origin was about creating snapshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is done by simply creating a new volume and then copying over the data from the original one with:

```
dd if=/dev/mapper/original_thin_volume of=/dev/mapper/new_thin_volume conv=sparse
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way:

```
virt-sparsify indisk outdisk
```